# Getting half output or no output from flask app deployed on an Ubuntu server mod_wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, apache, ubuntu, flask, mod-wsgi

I have installed a Flask App on an Ubuntu server using mod_wsgi. When I am calling it from my local machine, it is sometimes responding, sometimes not responding at all, and sometimes giving just half output and then it gets stuck. It was running fine until yesterday but since today it has not been working normally. I have googled regarding this issue but unfortunately, I could not resolve this issue until now. Can anyone please guide me on this issue?

My client code:

```
import time
import http.client
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def timePrint():

    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("47.123.456.123") # a 
    conn.request("POST", '/timePrint')
    res = conn.getresponse()
    if int(res.code) > 199 and int(res.code) < 206:
        data = res.read()
        pattern = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
        dateTime = datetime.strptime(data.decode("utf-8"), pattern)
        print(dateTime)

while True:
        timePrint()
```

My server code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import flask
import sys
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/timePrint", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def timePrint():
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        currentTime=str(datetime.now())
        return  currentTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

                ServerName 47.123.456.123

                ServerAdmin admin@47.123.456.123

                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskCathy/flaskapp.wsgi

                <Directory /var/www/FlaskCathy/FlaskApp/>
                         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

                         AllowOverride None

                         Require all granted

                </Directory>

                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskCathy/FlaskApp/static

                <Directory /var/www/FlaskCathy/FlaskApp/static/>

                         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

                         AllowOverride None

                         Require all granted


                </Directory>

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

                LogLevel warn

                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My flaskapp.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskCathy/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

Can anyone please guide me on this issue?

Comment: _sometimes responding, sometimes not responding at all, and sometimes giving just half output_ Set flask's and apache's log's to be as detailed as possible (debug level?) and see what's going on when your service behaves badly.

Comment: It is giving the last log message as  
""-" 408 0 "-" "-"

Comment: caught SIGTERM, shutting down . this is the another error in the log file